# Iterating Through Records - Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I need to know how to iterate through records in CR2008 and when it reaches a record that is NOT NULL, record that in a variable.

I have a formula called "frmAccum" that I drop in the details section and suppress it.  I use this to gather information for each record that's processed.  I also have a formula called frmReset where I rest the stringvar "person_name" to "" and I can drop that in a Group header to reset after a grouping.

When it comes across a person_name field that is NOT NULL and is not empty, I want it to retain the name in a variable to be used in the report header.

So something like this:

```
stringvar person_name;
whileprintingrecords;

If ({Command.personname} <> "") Then
    person_name := {Command.personname}
```

I can't get this combination to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't get a response and figured out how to modify my command, so that it put the name in all the fields in the column, so I can pull it now via Command.personname.

If anyone comes back to read this and knows how to do this via Crystal syntax, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
whileprintingrecords;

stringvar person_name;

If Isnull({Command.personname}) Then
    person_name := {Command.personname}
```